# Rails quiz application passing value via radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a basic quiz app to learn rails radio button.

I have quiz model with fields- question, option1, option2..option4 and answer.

My index.html :

```
<% @quizzes.each do |quiz| %>
<h1><%= quiz.question %> </h1>
      <% question_count = question_count + 1 %>
        <%=  radio_button_tag question_count,  quiz.option1 %>       
           <%= quiz.option1 %></br>
        <%=  radio_button_tag question_count, quiz.option2 %>
            <%= quiz.option2 %></br>
        <%=  radio_button_tag question_count,  quiz.option3 %>
            <%= quiz.option3 %></br>
        <%=  radio_button_tag question_count,  quiz.option4 %>
            <%= quiz.option4 %></br>
<%= button_to 'Submit', check_quiz_path(quiz), :method => :post %>

<% end %>
```

My problem is very simple. I want to check value of radio button in my check method of Quiz controller. I am unable to figure out how to do that.
Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By validate you mean making sure at a radio button is checked?

Comment: no i don't want to validate checkbox checked or not. I want to validate answer in controller

Comment: @Cyzanfar question updated

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to validate that a user must select one option before submitting you'll need an Active Record validations in your Quiz model
(*app/model/quiz.rb*). Take a look at the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) on that subject.

***UPDATE***

The only way of passing information from your views to your controller is from params. In the create action (method) in your `QuizzesController` you'll need to access the params passed and compare it with the value of your answer.

A good way to debug your code is to drop at a specific moment in time in you code. I use [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry) which is a Ruby gem that helps you debug your code.

This is what I would do to check if my params are passed correctly:

first install the gem `gem install pry` then `bundle install`

now in your QuizzesController

```
require 'pry'
class QuizzesController < ApplicationController

 def create
  binding.pry
 end

end
```

Now start your server `rails s` then browse to whatever route the quiz is on, select your answer and submit the answer. Once you do that your POST request will hit the create method and your program will hang into pry. If you go take a look at your bash you'll see that you can directly interact with your create method. simply type `params` in your bash and that will return your params (which is a hash with key value pairs). This is  great way to understand what and how your program is executing and passing information.

Comment: no i don't want to validate checkbox checked or not. I want to validate answer in controller

Comment: how do you call an answer on a question? something like
`@quizzes.each {|quiz| quiz.question.answer}` ?

Comment: simply i just want to pass value of checked radio button to controller method "check"

Comment: i will validate passed value in my "check" method with my answer

Answer (score 0):

User `params` on your controller method.

`params[:question_count]` to check value of checked radio.

**Update**:

I assume `question_count` is integer, so the name of each radio is become `name="5"`. This way you can acces its value with `params["5"]`.

It's better if you set the name with some string or or appended with string like `name="answer-5"`

Comment: Updated my answer. what is question_count?